# Use a specific gmail (one of several) account for `mailto` links

Tags: gmail, mailto

I use Gmail in Chrome both for my work and my personal email (two separate accounts). I set up the protocol handler so that `mailto:` links open a Gmail compose window in Chrome, but that window doesn't (AFAICT) allow me to specify from which Gmail account it will send.

Is there a way to indicate this in the "compose" window? Or is there a way to set up the `mailto:` protocol handler so that all `mailto:` links send messages from one particular account?

Answer (score 0):

you could write a small extension to rewrite the urls `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/` (default) to `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/4/` for example.

I haven't done it myself but there are extensions that do these kinds of automatic url redirects, it shouldn't be too hard to pull off.

separately, this isn't an exact answer to the question, but this extension is pretty helpful for setting default google accounts among multiple alternatives.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/default-account-for-googl/bnocikekcdchphdpfffcgikiblhnkdad

Answer (score 0):

Use this URL:

`https://mail.google.com/mail/b/${userEmail}/extsrc=mailto&url=${encodeURIComponent(mailtoUrl)}&view`;